# Does CheckClassAdapter require using precise values for visitMaxs?

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

When creating a class using ASM, it is convenient to pass meaningless values to `visitMaxs`

```
public static byte[] createClassNoAdapter() {
    var cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

    cw.visit(Opcodes.V9, ACC_PUBLIC, "TestClass", null, "java/lang/Object" , new String[0]);

    var mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "test", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitCode();
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
    mv.visitMaxs(-1, -1);
    mv.visitEnd();

    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

However, I'm trying to diagnose some problems, and using a `CheckClassAdapter`. If I explicitly pass correct values for `maxStack` and `maxLocals`, this works.

```
public static byte[] createClassAdapter() {
    var cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

    var cv = new CheckClassAdapter(cw);
    cv.visit(Opcodes.V9, ACC_PUBLIC, "TestClass2", null, "java/lang/Object" , new String[0]);

    var mv = cv.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "test", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitCode();
    mv.visitInsn(Opcodes.RETURN);
    mv.visitMaxs(1, 1);
    mv.visitEnd();

    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

While this works, it's less convenient.  Calling `visitMaxs(-1, -1)` results in an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid max stack (must be an unsigned short): -1
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.checkUnsignedShort(CheckMethodAdapter.java:1133)
at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitMaxs(CheckMethodAdapter.java:1027)
at com.justinblank.strings.Example.createClassAdapter(Example.java:35)
at com.justinblank.strings.Example.main(Example.java:47)
```

The source code makes it clear that you must pass a non-negative value, but passing 0 does not work either:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data flow checking option requires valid, non zero maxLocals and maxStack.
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter$1.visitEnd(CheckMethodAdapter.java:456)
    at org.objectweb.asm.MethodVisitor.visitEnd(MethodVisitor.java:783)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter.visitEnd(CheckMethodAdapter.java:1036)
    at com.justinblank.strings.Example.createClassAdapterZero(Example.java:51)
    at com.justinblank.strings.Example.main(Example.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Trying to set an inexistant local variable 0
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Frame.setLocal(Frame.java:208)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.computeInitialFrame(Analyzer.java:466)
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Analyzer.java:163)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckMethodAdapter$1.visitEnd(CheckMethodAdapter.java:453)
    ... 4 more
```

Is there some way to avoid manually calculating the stack while using CheckClassAdapter?

Comment: As far as I can see from the source code, it doesn’t require correctly calculated values but only checks that the values are in the 0..65535 range. That’s a pity as using a value outside the range documented that the values are not used at all. But there’s no way to turn that check off.

Comment: Edited: I saw the same line as you and tried passing 0, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that it's safe to use a very large value. The following value seemed to work for me in several cases:

```
public static byte[] createClassAdapterHacky() {
    var cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);

    var cv = new CheckClassAdapter(cw);
    cv.visit(Opcodes.V9, ACC_PUBLIC, "TestClass3", null, "java/lang/Object" , new String[0]);

    var mv = cv.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "test", "()V", null, null);
    mv.visitCode();
    mv.visitMaxs(Short.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1, Short.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1);
    mv.visitEnd();

    return cw.toByteArray();
}
```

I don't know for sure if this is the proper solution, but it seems to work.

Comment: It appears that if you do this and receive certain errors, the adapter will print all 65535 variable types that are on the stack at this point.

Comment: I don’t know whether `Short.MAX_VALUE * 2 + 1` is really more readable (or self-documenting) than, e.g. `0xFFFF`. Another issue is that this won’t notice when the code has been changed to initialize the `ClassWriter` to not calculate the actual values. Instead, you get inefficient class files. Maybe, it’s worth filing a feature request to the ASM maintainers, to add support for the `COMPUTE_…` options to `CheckClassAdapter`. I also could imagine a new API, a `computeMax()` method that can be invoked instead of `visitMaxs(…)`; that would be even cleaner than `visitMaxs(-1, -1)`…

Comment: Agreed (and hadn't thought to use hex, but it's clearly better). I had planned to file an issue unless I got a clear answer.